# Call a subprocedure with an input argument inside a shape

Tags: vba, visio

My goal is to call a macro (with input of specific information from the shape) inside a shape in the MS VISIO application.

The macro is to open a PDF datasheet of the specific shapes (the element in my block diagram).

I have an idea to trigger the macro from the specific shape, which is inserting action section and using runaddon function to run the subprocedure (using shell to open a specific PDF file).

**Question:**

How do I pass an argument (type of string) of the shape (in my case it is a PDF file name for this shape) to the subprocedure? If that can be achieved, I can open each shape's corresponding datasheet.

How do I save the input argument value (type string) inside each shape?

And how do I call them inside VBA subprocedure?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visio has hyperlinks. You can just add a hyperlink to your shape pointing to your PDF, and the menu item action as well as click behavior will be added automatically.

So, click Ctrl+K to add a hyperlink, or use "insert" menu.
You can also add hyperlink programmatically, or by linking to a data source (like excel). Also you can build URL of the link as a formula, out of shape data, like shape text.

If you still want to do it with vba macro, you can try CALLTHIS function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa212649(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#example-1